# How to properly load a DataGridView after form is fully visible?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have 2 forms. In form one I enter information and the second one works as a helper to get codes for the first one(using it with ShowDialog() method). Since the information retrieved in the second form comes from a database that is being remotely accessed sometimes it takes a few seconds so what i did is to move the lengthy method that loads the information into the `DataGridView` to a BackgroundWorker, the code in the DoWork is:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
    //Method to retrieve records
    });                             

}
```

and start it in the form's `Shown()` method. Now, my problem is, that the first time an instance of the form is created it works perfect but from the first time on it shows up like this:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hide gridview until data has loaded and you have assigned datasource to it after that make it visible.

Comment: It still does the same as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all read the documentation about types you use:

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.<sup>[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup>

Because of the `this.Invoke(...` you basically do all the fetching from database on the UI thread, and that's why your form isn't redrawn.

In order to fix this issue:

1. Remove `this.Invoke` and any other code that accesses UI controls from the `DoWork` event handler. In that handler you only want to fetch the records from database, and NOT update any UI.
2. Move your UI updating code to the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler.
3. Last but not least, you may want to start your data loading not on the form's `Shown` event but rather [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx), because [it precedes the `Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx) and is raised before the form is displayed.

Comment: Oh, i didn't even know i couldn't do UI stuff in DoWork. I saw some people doing it here when searching for a question like this so I assumed it was correct x_x. I did what you said and it solved the issue perfectly, Thank you.